# JIRA XML RPC response always the same

Tags: xml-rpc, jira

I know I would rather use a library like Apache's XMLRPC client but when I do the following:

```
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(JIRA_URL).openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
```

... and then send the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=ISO-8859-1"?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>jira1.login</methodName>
  <params>
    <param><value><string>someUser</string></value></param>
    <param><value><string>pwd123</string></value></param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```

I am always getting:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:&#32;com.atlassian.jira.rpc.xmlrpc.JiraXmlRpcService.getProjectsNoSchemes()
```

Now why is it even saying a method I didn't request? Besides the method does exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: Well I am fine with the NoSuchMethodException, because the signature seems to lack the String token argument. But I was wondering, why I am getting that method at all; it's not even on my payload.