# NoSuchMethodError being thrown on custom class instantiation

Tags: java, eclipse, import, build-process

I've done a pull from git from repository, and ended up getting this error during run time. The error is being thrown on instantiation of a custom class - a class which is declared in the same project as the class throwing the error. I have read that my build process is faulty and i need to ensure that my the class files that i'm actually running are updated when you compile..

I've cleaned project, recompiled and deployed, with no luck. Can anybody offer wisdom?

Thanks

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: I suspect the exception tells you *which* method is missing. It would help if you'd show the full exception details.

Comment: ya it tells me exactly what method is missing. However is declared in the same location.. Stacktrace i've put up, but i'll have to take it down again soon

Comment: please bear in mind that these classes have not changed in a very long time! its eclipse is the problem here.

Comment: No, this is a Runtime Exception. That the class hasn't changed in a long time might actually be the problem--code calling it is expecting a method to be in the .class file that's not there.  What *is* your build process, and does it actually include recompiling the classes mentioned in the exception?

Comment: i managed to get it sorted through maven rebuild, eclipse project clean, redeploying ejbs and redepoying app on server. Thanks for the help!