# how to using service method in java?

Tags: java, spring

I am new to service method in java i don't solve this problem my application, can you any solve this problem .. How can i solve this errors only ...

java:

```
 textStripper.setHtmlService(htmlService);
    textStripper.setHtmlDocument(html);
```

Errors:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.setHtmlService(Lpdf2html/service/intf/HTMLService;)V
        at pdf2html.service.impl.PDF2HTMLServiceImpl.convertPage(PDF2HTMLServiceImpl.java:60)
        at pdf2html.Main.main(Main.java:27)
Java Result: 1
```

...

when track errors, i can command this line i got only text... service not working..

Comment: Can You Post Your Code ?

Comment: This is not related to service issue, this link will help back ground of exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: Is this post written in English or is it some other language I don't know yet?

Comment: I got @sreemanthpulagam...

Comment: but I am using Net Beans Project -> properties->libraires->select jar path, I did this way but it not working that steps

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the jar version you downloaded has the class and methods you secified in your code.

Download the JAD GUI (Java Decompiler) from the link below

http://jd.benow.ca/

using the jad open the specific jar and see whether u can find the class name **"PDFTextStripper"**  has method **setHtmlService**. If not download the latest jar file and set it to the java build path.