# Error - org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity.<init>

Tags: java, eclipse, apache

I am using Eclipse in creating the java project. I am getting the below error and I don't understand what is missing. Please help

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)V
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request.bodyString(Request.java:282)
    at com.urbanairship.api.client.APIClient.pushRequest(APIClient.java:113)
    at com.urbanairship.api.client.APIClient.push(APIClient.java:200)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:76)
```

Comment: It says that compiler couldn't find a method. `Init` - is it constructor. As this comes from 3rd party library it is probably incompatibility problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror