# Android studio App engine datastore integration - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-datastore

I have created a method in and exposed it using Google Endpoints. All I want is to **save and retrieve data from Google DataStore**.

When I try to test using the API Explorer , I get the following error-

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError**

I have attached the code below

```
 @ApiMethod (name ="mTest")
    public void mTest(@com.google.api.server.spi.config.Named("UName") String UName) throws IOException {

        DatastoreService datastoreService;
        datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Transaction tx=datastoreService.beginTransaction();
        try {
            Key userKey = KeyFactory.createKey("USERS_PK", UName);
            Entity userEntity=new Entity("M_USERS",userKey);
            userEntity.setProperty("TestColumn","TestColumnValue");
            datastoreService.put(userEntity);
            tx.commit();
        }finally {
            if (tx.isActive()){
                tx.rollback();
            }
        }
}
```

The error is hit on  **datastoreService.put(userEntity);**

Please find the stack trace below :

```
Jun 29, 2014 5:12:20 PM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
INFO: cause={0}

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.getAppIdNamespace()Lcom/google/appengine/api/datastore/AppIdNamespace;
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyTranslator.convertToPb(KeyTranslator.java:49)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityTranslator.convertToPb(EntityTranslator.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:203)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:180)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$BatchIterator.<init>(Batcher.java:177)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$2.<init>(Batcher.java:312)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher.getBatches(Batcher.java:312)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.doBatchPut(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:536)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.put(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:490)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$2.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:95)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$2.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:92)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionRunner.runInTransaction(TransactionRunner.java:29)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:92)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:81)
    at GetMedSoonAppEngineProject.GMS_UserRegistrationEndpoint.mTest(GMS_UserRegistrationEndpoint.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:124)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:82)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Jun 29, 2014 5:12:20 PM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
SEVERE: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.getAppIdNamespace()Lcom/google/appengine/api/datastore/AppIdNamespace;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.getAppIdNamespace()Lcom/google/appengine/api/datastore/AppIdNamespace;
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyTranslator.convertToPb(KeyTranslator.java:49)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityTranslator.convertToPb(EntityTranslator.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:203)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:180)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$BatchIterator.<init>(Batcher.java:177)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$2.<init>(Batcher.java:312)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher.getBatches(Batcher.java:312)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.doBatchPut(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:536)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.put(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:490)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$2.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:95)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$2.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:92)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionRunner.runInTransaction(TransactionRunner.java:29)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:92)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:81)
    at GetMedSoonAppEngineProject.GMS_UserRegistrationEndpoint.mTest(GMS_UserRegistrationEndpoint.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:124)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:82)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Any Help is appreciated! I am stuck up with this for a month and I am not able to find the solution.

IDE : Android Studio 0.61
OS : Windows 8

Comment: Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

Comment: Yes! This occurs when I test it in the api explorer. can you suggest a solution for the same?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change the version of Objectify library in the build.gradle file of your backend to 4.0b to 5.0.3

This is may sound irrelevant but objectify 4.0b library has same classes with same package name which are present in appengine sdk like com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.

when you deploy the app backend the appengine classes are overridden by objectify classes and hence when you try to call some method it is throwing error.

This is solved in objectify 5.0.+

Comment: To be a little more specific, old versions of Objectify include GWT super-source and Gradle is incorrectly compiling source files inside the jar. In Objectify v4.1 and later, the GWT adapters have been moved to a separate jar.

Comment: I imported Objectify 5.1.4 but I still have same issue :( I even cleaned project but have same problem on local machine and live server

Comment: oh, I forgot to put application Id in my appengine-web.xml file. Once I added it is working fine on local and live. Have no idea why it can be source of same error :(