# "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.<init>-Appium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have recently started appium for iOS programming and when I executed the below mentioned script

```
package com.OSsample.test;

import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class sampleiOS 
{
    public static AppiumDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("appiumVersion", "1.4.1");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.3");
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6");
        cap.setCapability("app", "Settings");
        try {
            driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/driver/hub"), cap);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I am encountering this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.<init>(Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/ErrorCodes;Z)V
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<clinit>(AppiumDriver.java:46)
at com.OSsample.test.sampleiOS.main(sampleiOS.java:21)
```

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this issue

Comment: I think you should take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: This is a problem of incompatibilities between different libraries. What are your project dependencies? If your project is Maven post the relevant output from `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: I am trying to run it on my appium server

Comment: Now i am getting this error
"That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP resource"