# Android: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Landroid\/os\/Handler when calling FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()

Tags: android, facebook, android-handler

I have an Android app used Facebook for login.
However, I got some user bug reports reporting "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" when doing facebook initialization.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Landroid\/os\/Handler;.
at android.support.v4.content.l.(LocalBroadcastManager.java:110)
at android.support.v4.content.k.(LocalBroadcastManager.java:110)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(LocalBroadcastManager.java:102)
at com.facebook.internal.BoltsMeasurementEventListener.open(BoltsMeasurementEventListener.java:53)
at com.facebook.internal.BoltsMeasurementEventListener.getInstance(BoltsMeasurementEventListener.java:70)
at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:169)
at my.app.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:119)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4464)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What would be the possible cause of this issue?

Comment: maybe they are using old devices?

Comment: @SacreDeveloper one of the user use Sony z3 with android 4.4.4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror

Answer (score 1):

I am too late to answer (Help to others) but I solved this problem and I am not sure if it can work for others too.

I added a **release key hash** together with the debug key hash in the developers.facebook.com/................
 and it worked.

Lets see if it works for others too.