# I use Jetty, I encounter error in following image

Tags: spring, hibernate, jetty

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M1:run (default-cli) on
>   project springDAT-MVC: Execution default-cli of goal
>   org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M1:run failed: An API
>   incompatibility was encountered while executing
>   org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M1:run:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils$FieldCallback;)

[image]

Comment: Could be a duplicate of [How do I fix a NoSuchMethodError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror). Also you should try to write questions that are [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For clearly, post your code, project folder structure and full errors message.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a version conflict. At runtime a jar is used where the  method ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields does not exist.
Search in the Ide in which jar the Spring ReflectionUtils is declareds,
than you can usen use mvn dependency:tree to see which versions are used by Maven at runtime...