# App Engine "NoSuchMethodError" for "Stopwatch.createUnstarted"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

My app is throwing "NoSuchMethodError" and I have no idea, why!

Detail:

```
05:55:50.777
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backend method
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createUnstarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:156)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl.createOrReplace(GcsServiceImpl.java:70)
    at com.rave79.endpoint.StreamEndpoint.upload(StreamEndpoint.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:44)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:363)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:113)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:58)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:310)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:302)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:443)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anyone have any idea, what is wrong?

On Android side I get:

```
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err: {
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:   "code": 503,
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:   "errors": [
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     {
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:       "domain": "global",
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:       "message": "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createUnstarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;",
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:       "reason": "backendError"
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     }
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:   ],
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:   "message": "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createUnstarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;"
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err: }
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
04-25 12:55:51.007 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
04-25 12:55:51.011 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
04-25 12:55:51.011 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
04-25 12:55:51.011 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at com.rave79.activity.PostDetailActivity$2.doInBackground(PostDetailActivity.java:186)
04-25 12:55:51.011 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at com.rave79.activity.PostDetailActivity$2.doInBackground(PostDetailActivity.java:148)
04-25 12:55:51.011 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-25 12:55:51.011 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-25 12:55:51.011 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-25 12:55:51.011 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-25 12:55:51.011 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-25 12:55:51.011 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-25 12:55:51.011 1040-1471/com.rave79 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This seems to start to occur after I updated my android studio for version 2

But the problem is in server side, and not in app.

My Dependencies:

```
 <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <!-- Common module dependency -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-datastore-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>v1beta2-rev1-2.1.0</version>
         </dependency>

        <!-- Cloud Endpoints -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Objectify -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>${objectify.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Google Guice DI Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${guice.version}</version>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
      <version>RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

        <!-- javax REST API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guice</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey Multipart, uncomment if you are uploading files using Jersey -->
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         -->
         <!-- Google Guava library -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Per [the documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html#createUnstarted()), `createUnstarted()` has only existed since Guava 15. Make sure at least that version is available in the app engine

Comment: Also, this might be considered a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror