# Error Signing APK with jarsigner Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, jarsigner

I am running this command:

> jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore
>   my-release-key.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk alias_name

but I get this error
[image]

how do i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that your **unsigned APK and keystore** are not located in the same folder.

You'll need to know the path to both the unsigned APK and the keystore from previos step. I recommend **moving them into the same directory** so the command is easier to type.

Instead of `android-release-unsigned.apk` you should use name of your app like this `NameOfMyApp.apk`

Whole command should look like this:

`jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore NameOfMyApp.keystore NameOfMyApp.apk NameOfMyApp`

This will work only if you have your `NameOfMyApp.keystore`

More about this at [Chapter 6: Publishing your app](https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html)

Comment: What is the name of your unsigned APK and keystore file?

Comment: jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystor
e myStore.keystore platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned
.apk myStore

Comment: I recommend moving unsigned APK and keystore into the same directory and then run the command. P.S. You have empty space in `android-release-unsigned .apk`

Comment: I have tried that too. See in the picture, the error is at sun.security.pcks7. I don't think its my syntax thats the issue

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is uninstalling and reinstalling the JDK.

I followed this:

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html