# update method GameWorld doesn't work

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm learning libGDX through this tutorial: http://www.kilobolt.com/day-4-gameworld-and-gamerenderer-and-the-orthographic-camera.html

I've got a problem when I try to run the DesktopLauncher and after multiple research, no one has the same problem:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.kilobolt.gameworld.GameWorld.update(F)V
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.kilobolt.gameworld.GameWorld.update(F)V
at com.kilobolt.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:19)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:223)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)

  Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here's my GameScreen class:

```
package com.kilobolt.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.kilobolt.gameworld.GameRenderer;
import com.kilobolt.gameworld.GameWorld;

public class GameScreen implements Screen {

private GameWorld world;
private GameRenderer renderer;

public GameScreen() {
    Gdx.app.log("GameScreen", "Attached");
    world = new GameWorld();
    renderer = new GameRenderer();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    world.update(delta);
    renderer.render();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void show() {
    Gdx.app.log("GameScreen", "show called");
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    Gdx.app.log("GameScreen", "hide called");
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    Gdx.app.log("GameScreen", "pause called");
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    Gdx.app.log("GameScreen", "resume called");
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // Leave blank
}
```

}

My GameWorld class:

```
    package com.kilobolt.gameworld;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;

public class GameWorld {

public void update(float delta) {
    Gdx.app.log("GameWorld", "update");
}
}
```

And my GameRenderer class:

```
package com.kilobolt.gameworld;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;

public class GameRenderer {

public void render() {
    Gdx.app.log("GameRenderer", "render");
}
}
```

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding.

Comment: To add to what Andrew said, this `NoSuchMethod` error is low-level Java error that probably has nothing to do with LibGDX. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror) for some technical details.