# Weblogic server guava NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, guava, web-deployment, weblogic12c

I'm trying to deploy a web project with a war file on the weblogic server. But I'm getting an error like above,

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.<init>(EventBus.java:138)
```

I tried lastest and oldest versions of guava. In the oldest versions I got eventbus error (no defined this method in the old versions). In the newest versions I got the same error again.

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: It runs clearly in my editor (IntelliJ), when I try to run it on a weblogic server I get this error in deployment.

UPDATE:

I just added a weblogic.xml file like above in my WEB-INF path. No need any other configurasyon. The problem resolved for me thanks to @luc14n0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix a NoSuchMethodError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror)

Comment: I think no, because it runs clearly in my editor. It does not work on weblogic server in deployment.

Comment: which means that the classpath is being built differently between your editor and deployment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Weblogic 12c (12.1.3) ships with its own Guava dependency at Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/modules/com.google.common_1.2.0.0_11-0-2.jar

By telling WebLogic you prefer to use your own version, you avoid the conflict where it loads the wrong library.

In case of an EAR, add the following to *application.xml*:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
  <package-name>com.google.common.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

In case of a WAR, add the following to *weblogic.xml*:

```
<container-descriptor>
  <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

Comment: @enes it goes into _src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml_