# How do I fix a this NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: java, servlets, nosuchmethoderror

I'm getting a `NoSuchMethodError` error when running my Java program. What's wrong and how do I fix it?

```
>5월 16, 2017 11:44:31 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
심각: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/abs] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.abilsys.abs.common.taglib.selected.ABSSelectedTag.doFinally()V] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.abilsys.abs.common.taglib.selected.ABSSelectedTag.doFinally()V
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.abs.system.acnt.acntView_jsp._jspx_meth_abs_005fselect_005f0(acntView_jsp.java:926)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.abs.system.acnt.acntView_jsp._jspService(acntView_jsp.java:263)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:266)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1225)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1524)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1480)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My code is

```java
package com.abilsys.abs.common.taglib.selected;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport;

import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

import com.abilsys.abs.common.taglib.selected.generator.SelectedGenerator;
import com.abilsys.abs.common.taglib.selected.service.SelectedService;
import com.abilsys.abs.common.taglib.selected.vo.SelectedVO;

public class ABSSelectedTag extends TagSupport {

    protected String id = null;
    protected String name = null;
    protected String value = null;
    protected String cssClass = null;
    protected String groupCode = null;
    protected String contextPath = null;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getGroupCode() {
        return groupCode;
    }

    public void setGroupCode(String groupCode) {
        this.groupCode = groupCode;
    }

    public String getCssClass() {
        return cssClass;
    }

    public void setCssClass(String cssClass) {
        this.cssClass = cssClass;
    }

    public String getContextPath() {
        return contextPath;
    }

    public void setContextPath(String contextPath) {
        this.contextPath = contextPath;
    }

    public SelectedVO getSelectedVo(){
        SelectedVO selectedVO = new SelectedVO();

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)pageContext.getRequest();
        selectedVO.setContextPath(request.getContextPath().toString());
        selectedVO.setId(id);
        selectedVO.setName(name);
        selectedVO.setValue(value);
        selectedVO.setCssClass(cssClass);
        selectedVO.setGroupCode(groupCode);

        return selectedVO;
    }

    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try
        {
            SelectedVO selectedVo = getSelectedVo();            
            List<Map<String, Object>> codeList = null;
            List<Map<String, Object>> sCodeList = null;

            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) pageContext.getRequest();

            WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(pageContext.getServletContext());
            SelectedService selectedService = (SelectedService) ctx.getBean("selectedService");

            codeList = selectedService.getCodeInfo(groupCode);
            pageContext.getOut().print(SelectedGenerator.generator(selectedVo, codeList));  

        }
        catch(IOException ioe) 
        {
            throw new JspTagException("Error:  IOException while writing to the user");
        } 
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            throw new JspTagException("Error: " + e);
        }
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add how you run your application. It seems that you use a Web-Server. Add how the WAR file is created.

Answer (score 0):

With doEndTag() the doFinally method is invoked. When you are doing your try/catch block also have a finally block that executes doFinally(). I think this may be our problem. [Take a look here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TryCatchFinally.html)

Comment: From what I understand the program is looking for a doFinally method that hasn't been declared which is raising the error?

Comment: You can leave your ideas as comment, not as an answer

Comment: Oh is it not an answer? I thought that would fix the issue? Sorry if I've got it wrong, new to posting here.

Comment: If you thought that would fix the issue and it can be an answer, but if you thought you are giving tip/idea, leave a comment. We are here to learn, do mistake and learn from it as well, enjoy your ride :-)

Comment: I believe this answers the posters question (I hope at least). Thank you for your help and I will bare that in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare a method named `doFinally()` in `ABSSelectedTag` class:

```
public class ABSSelectedTag extends TagSupport {
    ...

    public void doFinally(){
        // your code goes here. I don't know what you want to do here.
    }
}
```

I make `doFinally()`'s return type as `void` by default. You can change it to `int`, `String`, etc.

For more information about `NoSuchMethodError`, read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35186/3922207).