# jmeter's junit request sampler wait conditions not working

Tags: selenium, junit, jmeter, webdriver, load-testing

**Hello,
I am working on junit load tests with jmeter. For this purpose, I am taking selenium webdriver and running it with selenium junit testing. when i run this code with junit on selenium webdriver,its working fine. But when i am trying to do the same thing with 20 threads in jmeter, then I am facing the following issues.**

```
Error -- test(org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler$AnnotatedTestCase): org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.until(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;
Trace -- java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.until(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at SeleniumTestNG.LoginLogoutTest.test(LoginLogoutTest.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler$AnnotatedTestCase.runTest(JUnitSampler.java:593)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler$1.protect(JUnitSampler.java:673)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler.sample(JUnitSampler.java:395)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:491)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:425)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Error -- test(org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler$AnnotatedTestCase): org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.until(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;
Trace -- java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.until(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at SeleniumTestNG.LoginLogoutTest.tearDown(LoginLogoutTest.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler.sample(JUnitSampler.java:399)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:491)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:425)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

please help me out with this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix a NoSuchMethodError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you jave all the libraries from your standalone JUnit project in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) as it looks like you are suffering from [this issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3606) or derivative.

Going forward make sure that your questions includes:

- code, you are trying to run
- dependency libraries of your project
- contents of "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
- jmeter.log file

Also be aware that there is a [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project which provides JMeter and Selenium integration, this way tests development will be much faster as you won't have to recompile your module, copy jar(s) to JMeter's "lib/junit" folder, restart JMeter, etc.