# MaxMind not working with Android

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x, maxmind

I am using MaxMind API to get insights from IP database using [this github link](https://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-java/)
. 
My gradle dependencies are

```
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
    exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
}
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
compile 'com.maxmind.geoip2:geoip2:2.9.0'
```

And my code for activity is

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
                                                                Process: com.mm.parentconcern, PID: 7852
                                                                java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method authenticate(Lorg/apache/http/auth/Credentials;Lorg/apache/http/HttpRequest;Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext;)Lorg/apache/http/Header; in class Lorg/apache/http/impl/auth/BasicScheme; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
                                                                    at com.maxmind.geoip2.WebServiceClient.getResponse(WebServiceClient.java:321)
                                                                    at com.maxmind.geoip2.WebServiceClient.responseFor(WebServiceClient.java:303)
                                                                    at com.maxmind.geoip2.WebServiceClient.insights(WebServiceClient.java:297)
                                                                    at com.mm.parentconcern.fragment.FlipBoardFragment$2.run(FlipBoardFragment.java:151)
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/35210/2724879

Comment: nice but solution?

Comment: Well, the first thing you need to do is to determine the problem NoSuchMethod is not enough!