# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException.getEcmaError()Ljava/lang/Object;

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse-neon

I'm developing a springmvc application when I try to open my javascript file I'am getting this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMA
>
> Exception.getEcmaError()Ljava/lang/Object;

The screenshot can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/930gX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Without additional information, it is difficult to identify directly your issue but I suspect that your error is due to one of the following causes:

- One of the jar files that you are embedding is not well included at building/compilation
- You are using an unappropriated version of one of the jar files you are including in your project.
- One of your classes is not well updated by your build process

Have a look at the following link for more information, it is well explained:

[how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror)

Comment: The problem here is with my javascript files.I am unable to open any of my JS files.