# App Engine Java Deployment Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.isSubtypeOf

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

We are getting following error on deploying on app engine server since last 4-5 days.  Sometimes deployment works, but most of the time it gives following errors.

Log snippet 1:

```
Error for /_ah/api/agentEndPoint/v1/addLead
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.isSubtypeOf(Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Z
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.model.Types.getArrayItemType(Types.java:138)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.registerService(SystemService.java:185)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService$Builder.build(SystemService.java:524)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet.createSystemService(EndpointsServlet.java:130)
```

Log snippet 2:

```
/_ah/api/taskEndPoint/v1/gettaskdetailresponse/TCB-16327
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet.service(EndpointsServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: Mention what you have done so for to solve this problem. This is common problem faced by many. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: This is a statement of fact - Please ask a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.1'
```

changed to

```
classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
```

Worked for me.

Also extra gradle clean remove the error

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin/blob/master/ANDROID_README.md