# Weblogic 12c - Soap webservice not working

Tags: java-8, weblogic, jax-ws, weblogic12c

I am facing problem with soap webservices on Weblogic 12c + Java 8.
When client call webservice, I am getting below error.
Same application was working on Weblogic 11g.

Please help.

> INFO: Received WS-I BP non-conformant Unquoted SoapAction HTTP header: processMessage
>   Dec 07, 2017 1:24:02 AM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit handle
>   **SEVERE: com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.Message.getHeaders()Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/HeaderList;
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.Message.getHeaders()Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/HeaderList;**
>   at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.impl.tube.server.WssTube.processResponse(WssTube.java:76)
>   at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1147)
>   at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
>   at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
>   at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
>   at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:419)
>   at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:868)
>   at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
>   at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:225)
>   at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:161)
>   at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:197)
>   at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:81)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at com.backbase.portal.foundation.commons.security.BackbaseAnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BackbaseAnonymousProcessingFilter.java:111)
>   at com.backbase.portal.foundation.commons.security.BackbaseAnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(BackbaseAnonymousProcessingFilter.java:76)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at com.backbase.mobile.security.jwt.JsonWebTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JsonWebTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:73)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3701)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
>   at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
>   at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
>   at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
>   at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
>   at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
>   at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
>   at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
>   at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
>   at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
>   at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
>   at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
>   at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)

Comment: you need to share the code which you are trying, so that we can reproduce to check your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following error

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
```

is usually encountered when the application's code is compiled against a different version of a library where the mentioned method existed, while in the newer it does not.

You may find more information here :

[How do I fix a NoSuchMethodError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror)