# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-7

My application works fine when I use *Embedded* `tomcat` to launch `Spring boot` application in `Spring STS` by clicking on `Run` on `Spring boot` App.

I then built a `JAR` with `Maven` using `mvn clean install`. While the `JAR` was built successfully, launching the application using `java -jar <jarname>` gives the following *stack-trace*:

> 09:07:37.688 [Tomcat-startStop-1] ERROR
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase - A child container failed
>   during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RailAssist]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_131]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [?:1.8.0_131]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [?:1.8.0_131]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start
>   component
>   [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RailAssist]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    ... 6 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RailAssist]]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5099)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    ... 7 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[/RailAssist]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:170)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5099)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    ... 7 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1125)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:170)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5099)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    ... 7 more 09:07:37.702 [main]
>   ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase - A child container
>   failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:356)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:96)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:535)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
>   [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   com.rail.assist.RailAssistApplication.main(RailAssistApplication.java:66)
>   [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>   [RailAssist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>   [RailAssist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>   [RailAssist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   [RailAssist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131] Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A
>   child container failed during start   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131] 09:07:37.726 [main] ERROR
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup
>   failed org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable
>   to start embedded container; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException:
>   Unable to start embedded Tomcat   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]   at
>   com.rail.assist.RailAssistApplication.main(RailAssistApplication.java:66)
>   [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>   [RailAssist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>   [RailAssist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>   [RailAssist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   [RailAssist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException:
>   Unable to start embedded Tomcat   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:115)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:535)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  ... 16 more Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardServer[-1]]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:356)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:96)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:535)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  ... 16 more Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Tomcat]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:356)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:96)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:535)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  ... 16 more Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:356)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:96)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:535)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  ... 16 more Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:356)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:96)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:535)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]  ... 16 more
>   Mahideeps-MacBook-Air:target mahideeptumati$

Comment: Likely a [version compatibility issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/) amongst your *`Java` distribution*, [`Spring-Boot` and other] *framework(s)* and external *libraries*. Additionally consider providing only relevant portions of *stack-trace* here along-with `DropBox` / `Google Drive` link to complete stack-trace

Comment: Post your `pom.xml` and `web.xml` file

Answer (score 0):

Remove/Delete `servlet-api.jar` from your java `install path jdk/lib/jre/ext/`. Let Spring use its own `tomcat-embed-core.jar`. Issue resolved for me.