# Issue sending email from Kotlin service

Tags: kotlin, jakarta-mail, apache-commons

I'm trying to make my first kotlin service and want it to send emails. I'm following this tutorial https://odalinjo.wordpress.com/2017/06/06/sending-mail-via-gmail-using-kotlin-and-commons-mail-library/, but I'm getting the following error....I'm not really sure what it even means?

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;Lcom/sun/mail/util/MailLogger;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [How do I fix a NoSuchMethodError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror). In short: you may have compiled your code against another version of the library that you are actually using at runtime or the libraries you use don't match the required dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you've got the wrong JavaMail jar files included in your project.  You only want the javax.mail.jar file, as described on the [JavaMail web site](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).

Comment: This was the ticket! Thanks so much, @BillShannon