# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet.toImmutableSortedSet(Ljava/util/Comparator;)Ljava/util/stream/Collector;

Tags: java, appium, appium-ios, appium-android, appium-desktop

I am getting an error with Appium setup unable to launch app. I am using configuration setup below:

```
java-client = 3.1.0
selenium-java = 3.11.0
appium-version = 1.7.0
```

Also added following dependency but still facing same problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Following capability that I have set:

```
File app = new File(prop.getProperty("apkFilePath"));
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability("DeviceName", "Redmi Note 5");
cap.setCapability("PlatformVersion", prop.getProperty("platformVersion"));
cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
cap.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
try{
    driver=new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

```
Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
    com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet.toImmutableSortedSet(Ljava/util/Comparator;)Ljava/util/stream/Collector;
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.lambda$validate$4(NewSessionPayload.java:199)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:372)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:373)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.validate(NewSessionPayload.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.(NewSessionPayload.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:114)
```

Please take a look into this how to resolve this problem.. i am trying last two days but still facing same problem.
there is any other ways to resolve this appium setup kindly suggest...
Waiting for kind response...

Answer (score 1):

`selenium-java-3.11` requires Guava [`23.6-jre as per the pom.xml`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.11.0/jar):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>23.6-jre</version>
  <classifier></classifier>
</dependency>
```

You have downgraded to much older Guava version, remove your own version from the pom.xml and let selenium pick up the required version.

Comment: thanks for the reply i have changed guava to 23.6-jre but getting an error : org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. Details: The desiredCapabilities object was not valid for the following reason(s): 'deviceName' can't be blank (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 488 milliseconds

Comment: @manishkumar you should open another question with more details. It seems unrelated to the original issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might have clashing versions of `Guava` in your classpath (i.e signatures of the method you are trying to invoke, are different). 
I had previously faced `NoSuchMethodError` and it actually originates from clashing versions of jars. 
Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror).
Also take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3538)

Comment: One possibility is that you have compiled the code with one `Guava` jar and running the program in deployment with another version of jar which was the case when I had faced `NoSuchMethodError` error.

Answer (score 0):

try using **platformVersion** instead of **PlatformVersion** and **deviceName** instead of **DeviceName**.

```
cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Redmi Note 5");
cap.setCapability("platformVersion", prop.getProperty("platformVersion"));
//or you can use
//cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0"); //your android os version directly
```

> you don't need to use guava dependency if you are using maven project
>   to add selenium-java