# Test FX application using Marathon driver - Unable to establish connection with the application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, marathon, marathontesting

Issue- Test FX application using Marathon driver -  Unable to establish connection with the application.
Steps-

1. FX based Client Application Launch happens successfully using marathon profile set.
   2.Exception while setting driver.
2. Unable to set text in textfield.

[Code shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41lr6.png)

Output after launch-

FAILED: createJavaProfile
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet.toImmutableSortedSet(Ljava/util/Comparator;)Ljava/util/stream/Collector;
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.lambda$validate$3(NewSessionPayload.java:191)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:441)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:442)
at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.validate(NewSessionPayload.java:207)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.(NewSessionPayload.java:152)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:99)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:94)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:69)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:138)
at net.sourceforge.marathon.javadriver.JavaDriverCommandExecutor.execute(JavaDriverCommandExecutor.java:135)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:582)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:136)
at net.sourceforge.marathon.javadriver.JavaDriver.(JavaDriver.java:156)
at net.sourceforge.marathon.javadriver.JavaDriver.(JavaDriver.java:131)
at net.sourceforge.marathon.javadriver.JavaDriver.(JavaDriver.java:112)
at io.mosio.demograph.demo.Demo2stack.createJavaProfile(Demo2stack.java:60)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Comment: JavaProfile profile1 = new JavaProfile(LaunchMode.JAVA_COMMAND_LINE); //LaunchMode.JAVA_COMMAND_LINE
  profile1.setLaunchType(LaunchType.FX_APPLICATION);
  profile1.setWorkingDirectory("D:\\RegClientAutomation\\reg-client");
  profile1.setJavaCommand("D:\\RegClientAutomation\\reg-client\\jre\\jre\\bin\\java");
  profile1.addClassPath("D:\\RegClientAutomation\\registration-client-1.1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar");
  
  profile1.setMainClass("io.mosip");
driver = new JavaDriver(profile1); WebElement userId =driver.findElement(By.id("userId"));userId.sendKeys("");

Comment: Here is the code again..

Answer (score 0):

Please check the google guava version. As `marathon java driver 5.4.0.0` uses `selenium 3.14.0` which is internally dependent on `google.guava` version `25.0-jre`. That might be causing the issue.

Similar issue:

[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet.toImmutableSortedSet(Ljava/util/Comparator;)Ljava/util/stream/Collector;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52363536/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-collect-immutablesortedset-toimmu)