# Issues with DropWizard Gradle build

Tags: java, gradle, jackson, dropwizard

I imported a `Dropwizard` project into `Intellij IDEA` (using `Gradle Wrapper` from the project itself). Its working for others, but I end up in issue like this:

Here is the gist of gradle dependency.
https://gist.github.com/vineelya/d882bbd0885fafba785ca58f106dfc8b
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z

```
dependencies {
    compile (
            'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:' + dropwizardVersion,
            'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-hibernate:' + dropwizardVersion,
            'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-migrations:' + dropwizardVersion,
            'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-auth:' + dropwizardVersion,
            'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-assets:' + dropwizardVersion,
            'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-forms:'+ dropwizardVersion,
```

Comment: `requiresPropertyOrdering` is available since version `2.3`. So, you have classes which were build with `Jackson` in version at least `2.3` and need this method. What is you version of `Jackson`? See also: [How do I fix a NoSuchMethodError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror)

Comment: Other remote team mates have exactly the same code base and they are able to build and run. Its kind of confusing to me.

Comment: OK, but do you do exactly same steps? You must have some difference between your env and your team mate's envs.

Comment: They use Eclipse and I use Intellij, thats the only difference.

Comment: Have you tried to build project using `gradle` but not in `IntelliJ IDEA`, for example in console?

Comment: I tried but I have Java 11 installed and its trying to pick that up from outside IDE. I should try it by removing Java 11. Let me get that stack trace regardless.

Comment: @Vineel if you ask Gradle for the dependencies tree, what's the output?

Comment: Is ./gradlew dependencies the right command to use if I want to use standard gradle as that of the code base , irrespective of what version of Gradle is installed on my machine?Let me try, run and update here. I 'm working with an older Dropwizard project.

Comment: If you're using Gradle Wrapper then yes, it's the right command.

Comment: @LppEdd here the gist of Gradle dependency. https://gist.github.com/vineelya/d882bbd0885fafba785ca58f106dfc8b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two dependencies which are importing older versions of `Jackson Core`.

```
com.amazon.alexa:alexa-skills-kit:1.2
com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.1
```

While Gradle should always pick up the latest version, this might be causing your error.
Therefore, **exclude** them using

```
implementation('com.amazon.alexa:alexa-skills-kit:1.2') {
   exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
}

implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.1') {
   exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
}
```

Or, update them to a compatible, maybe the latest, version (e.g. see [MavenCentral](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client/1.28.0)).

To force the resolution of a specific version, you can use

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.8'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Please correct me if I m wrong. From the gist (https://gist.github.com/vineelya/d882bbd0885fafba785ca58f106dfc8b) , 2.8.8 is the net effective version picked up by Gradle. Google api client is providing 2.1.3 . So is it  necessary to exclude jackson from Google API client, because it looks like, 2.8.8 is picked up by Gradle regardless of  Google API providing 2.1.3.

Comment: @Vineel that is what I would like to believe. **However**, it seems the older version is picked up before the newer. I think the best approach is to force a single `Jackson Core` version, so to avoid confusion

Comment: How can it pick up the older version before. Am I missing something. It is showing in the gist that 2.8.8 is the picked version (at the top, its shows conflict resolution etc).

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.8 (conflict resolution) is what I see in the Gist.

Comment: @Vineel I don't know how to answer that question. However since the `requiresPropertyOrdering` method has been added in version `2.3+`, it seems this is really happening

Comment: @Vineel I edited the question to add how to force a specific version globally. I would also do a `./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies`