# Gradle can't find Apache commons

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, apache-commons-io

I have included this dependency in build.gradle with mavencentral repo.

```
  compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
```

When I do Gradle dependencies, gradle can't find this dependency. Here is the output.

compile - Dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'implementation' instead).

```
+--- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3 -> 1.11.228
|    +--- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:1.11.228
|    |    +--- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.228
|    |    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 -> 1.2
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4
|    |    |    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |    |    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.ion:ion-java:1.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.7.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.7
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:2.6.7
|    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.7
|    |    |    \--- joda-time:joda-time:2.8.1
|    |    \--- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:1.11.228
|    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.7.1 (*)
|    +--- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.228 (*)
|    \--- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:1.11.228 (*)
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0
***+--- org.apache.commons:commons-io:2.4 FAILED***
+--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
\--- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1
     \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the correct group is `commons-io`

```
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
```

Reimport, and it will be picked up.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LppEdd My bad. Thanks. some how I copied the wrong one from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4

Comment: @Vineel Apache projects have ambiguous groups, sometimes they use org.apache, sometimes it's the same as the name. Never understood which logic they use.

Comment: Thats right. Probably they why it didn't ring a bell and caught my attention. It sounded right, until I double checked after you pointed out.

Comment: could you help with my other question please, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55009341/issues-with-dropwizard-gradle-build?noredirect=1#comment96779089_55009341