# Spring boot application exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I am working on a Spring boot 1.5.9 application with JDK 1.8.2.

In debug mode with Intellij Ultimate edition, when the application tries to call a Rest API Method, there is an exception thrown like below;

I tried changing or adding different versions of 'com.faster' dependencies but no luck.

```
<jackson.version>2.8.8</jackson.version>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:279)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:657)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:387)
    at com.YYY.XXX.servicehelper.ContentServiceHelper.getPageContentWithLangNew(ContentServiceHelper.java:98)
    at com.YYY.XXX.servicehelper.ContentServiceHelper$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9d352ef9.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$1.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:344)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:326)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
```

Here is the dependency tree.

```
[INFO] -------------------------< com.YYY:XXXWeb >-------------------------
[INFO] Building XXXWeb 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ XXXWeb ---
[INFO] com.YYY:XXXWeb:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.YYY:XXXBackendLib:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.YYY:PaymentModuleLib:jar:0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.bkm:bexandroidsdk:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.session:spring-session:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.aerospike:spring-session-aerospike:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.aerospike:spring-data-aerospike:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:1.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.aerospike:aerospike-helper-java:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- com.aerospike:aerospike-client:jar:4.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.gnu:gnu-crypto:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.luaj:luaj-jse:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mindrot:jbcrypt:jar:0.3m:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jdt:ecj:jar:3.12.3:compile
[INFO] +- de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jolokia:jolokia-core:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.4.5:compile
[INFO] +- biz.paluch.logging:logstash-gelf:jar:1.11.2:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO]    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO]    |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.535 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-22T11:45:31+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you check if there is not additional version of jackson in the classpath. Do mvn dependency:tree and see if there is such.

Comment: Are you deploying your application in a container ? Is the container coming with its own version of jaxB

Comment: I am getting this error while trying to debug on my development machine.

Comment: Try to check [Module Dependency Diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55582143/8370915). In my case I had different versions of Jackson dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was not starting the Spring boot application with correct configuration. It should be started with the command `spring-boot:run`