# I'm getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" error

Tags: java

I am getting this problem in my 'Debug Console' in VS code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Car.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at CarTest2.main(CarTest2.java:23)
```

I was following an example from a book and it doesn't seem to work.

```java
class Car {
    String colour;
    String gearType;
    int door;

    Car() {
        this("white", "auto", 4);
    }

    Car(String colour) {
        this(colour, "auto", 4);
    }
    Car(String colour, String gearType, int door) {
        this.colour = colour;
        this.gearType = gearType;
        this.door = door;
    }
}

class CarTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car c1 = new Car();
        Car c2 = new Car("blue");

        System.out.println("c1.colour = " + c1.colour + ", c1.gearType = " + c1.gearType + ", c1.door = " + c1.door);
        System.out.println("c2.colour = " + c2.colour + ", c2.gearType = " + c2.gearType + ", c2.door = " + c2.door);
    }
}
```

Expected answer:

c1.colour = white, c1.gearType = "auto", c1.door = 4
c2.colour = blue, c2.gearType = "auto", c2.door = 4

Comment: The code you've posted works for me. Are you sure you recompiled both classes? Please show exactly how you compiled and ran the code.

Comment: Whatever book you are using, get rid of it. Not making your class public, not making your variables private, ...

Comment: Can not reproduce: https://ideone.com/qEmxh5

Comment: Clean your project and rebuild. It should work fine.

Comment: @Stultuske the book is for beginners of Java, it's just teaching the basics of Java...(I guess)

Comment: I just used cmd to compile and run and it worked fine. What's wrong with the VS code?

Comment: @LearKing Learn the basics in the proper way. Make it right first time. Follow the good code guidelines even if its a learning code.

Comment: @LearKing yes, but it teaches the basics wrong. It's harder to unlearn bad material compared to learning it correct from the start.

Comment: Well thats why its called learning! :-) . BTW, clean the VSCode project and execute, it should work. Softwares mess up some times.

Comment: The answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror explain the (general) cause for this kind of problem.  The specific problem is that you (or your IDE) are not recompiling your code properly.