# No method found login error cuba platform

Tags: spring, cuba-platform

Environment
Platform version: 7.2

Description of the bug or enhancement

create new tenant and following exception comes when try to login

```
08:45:00.081 ERROR c.h.c.s.a.AuthenticationServiceBean - Login error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.haulmont.cuba.core.global.Metadata.create(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at com.haulmont.addon.sdbmt.core.sys.MultiTenancySecurityHandler.addTenantIdConstraint(MultiTenancySecurityHandler.java:144) ~[sdbmt-core-1.3.3.jar:na]
at com.haulmont.addon.sdbmt.core.sys.MultiTenancySecurityHandler.compileTenantConstraints(MultiTenancySecurityHandler.java:110) ~[sdbmt-core-1.3.3.jar:na]
at com.haulmont.addon.sdbmt.core.sys.MultiTenancySecurityHandler.compileConstraints(MultiTenancySecurityHandler.java:91) ~[sdbmt-core-1.3.3.jar:na]
at com.haulmont.addon.sdbmt.core.LoginEventListener.onApplicationEvent(LoginEventListener.java:39) ~[sdbmt-core-1.3.3.jar:na]
at com.haulmont.addon.sdbmt.core.LoginEventListener.onApplicationEvent(LoginEventListener.java:27) ~[sdbmt-core-1.3.3.jar:na]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror might help

Comment: perhaps is compile time versus runtime. It looks like a library implementation inside your dependencies implementing old interface method (only in runtime)

Answer (score 0):

sdbmt-core-1.3.3.jar corresponds to the multitenancy add-on version compatible with CUBA 7.0.
CUBA 7.2 had some breaking changes when comparing to 7.0, so you have binary incompatibility exception here.

See compatibility matrix here:
https://github.com/cuba-platform/multitenancy-addon/blob/master/README.md#from-the-marketplace

For projects based on CUBA 7.2 you should use multitenancy add-on version 2.0.0.