# Cloud Vision API quickstart code not working: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, java-8, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to run the code [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-java). However it is returning a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.disableServiceConfigLookUp()Lio/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder;` I've determined that the error is caused by the line `try (ImageAnnotatorClient vision = ImageAnnotatorClient.create())`.

I've looked online but I haven't been able to find any information on this other than it potentially being a versioning issue. However, I'm using dependencies stated on the quickstart guide so I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: did you set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ?

Answer (score 1):

‘**NoSuchMethodError**’ is a generic non-Google Java runtime error caused by a maven dependency conflict. This is specifically a Java dependency conflict concerning the ‘**io.grpc**’ library as noted in the error.

As explained in the [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html), you can use the following command to see what version of “**io.grpc**” dependency is installed in your **local environment** that is causing the issue:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=io.grpc
```

Once you have identified the conflicting Java dependency after running the previous command, you can then try to resolve the conflict by performing these generic steps:

1. Try a clean install of maven: `mvn clean install` and execute the file.
2. You can update all versions to the latest release: `mvn versions:use-latest-releases` and execute the file.
3. Follow the additional recommendations noted in this [similar Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror) which addresses the “NoSuchMethodError” issue.

> As a workaround, I tested the Quickstart code in [Google Cloud
> Shell](http://%20https://cloud.google.com/shell) and it runs flawlessly (as Cloud Shell has pre-installed
> packages which are up to-date and [reset upon closing](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works)). So for
> testing purposes you can run the code in the [Cloud Shell](http://%20https://cloud.google.com/shell) instead
> of in your local environment.