# [For help]javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

Tags: java

This project have these errors after I uploaded it to server, but it can run in local.
Thanks for your answer.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getCellTypeEnum()Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType;
excelUtil.ExcelUtil2.paike(ExcelUtil2.java:466)
excelUtil.ExcelUtil2.handleExcel(ExcelUtil2.java:66)
upload.HandleServlet.doGet(HandleServlet.java:71)
upload.HandleServlet.doPost(HandleServlet.java:95)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

)

Comment: The Apache POI library is not available on your server or in your application, or it's the wrong version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix a NoSuchMethodError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I changed my tomcat's version to solve this problem.