# RemoteTestNG detected TestNG 7.3.0 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.TestNG.configure(Lorg/testng/CommandLineArgs

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

I have a legacy project on which I'm working on. We still use java6 on some projects; And I do not manage to run testNG on my eclipse.
Seems like the problem is the used testNG version.

I migrated testng-5.5-jdk15 to 7.3.0 just trying to fix that. I'm using eclipse version 2020-09 (4.17.0).

It worked 2 times. After those attempts, I have again the error below:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.3.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.TestNG.configure(Lorg/testng/CommandLineArgs;)V
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.configure(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:75)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:235)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

I found some similar issues/solutions which proposed to add the TestNG lib on the project path. But this did not help.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix a NoSuchMethodError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror)

Comment: No I tried every solution proposed, but it did not work.

Comment: Could you try with `testng-7.4.0`?